# Missing Type error on internally hosted Nuget site

Tags: .net, azure, nuget, nuget-server

I'm trying to fix an issue with local Nuget repository (on an Azure VM). This was working but recently has been giving the following error:

> ```
> The type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.Behavior, 
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' registered for extension 
> 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.Behavior' could not be loaded.
> ```

Checking in the GAC, this assembly does not seem to be present. This error follows a server migration so could be something that was installed on the previous machine but is not installed on the new machine. The Nuget site works fine on my local dev machine.

Does anyone know what this could be? What are the implications of removing references to this assembly from the machine.config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what caused it but I removed all references to ServiceModelSink in the machine.config and it now works.